# Issue with BizTalk register WCF-WSHttp adapter while calling web service

Tags: web-services, biztalk, iis-10, biztalk-2020

I published a schema as a web service on BizTalk 2020 with the BizTalk WCF Service Publishing Wizard.

On DEV environment (all-in-one), everything is fine and I can access the wsdl when I browse my service through IIS.

Then I deployed it on UAT environment (multi-server) and when I browse the service I got this error:

> The Messaging Engine failed to register the adapter for "WCF-WSHttp" for the receive location "/Scheduler/SchedulerServices/Service1.svc". Please verify that the receive location exists, and that the isolated adapter runs under an account that has access to the BizTalk databases.*

Here is the things I already checked :

- Application Pool is started
- The receive location exists.
- The receive location is enable.
- The user in Application Pool that run the web service has the good right in BizTalk database.
- The user in Application Pool is part of the BizTalk Isolated group.
- The user is actually able to access the BizTalk database and run the SP called *[BizTalkMgmtDb].dbo.[adm_getSettingsForIsolatedHostInstance]* and get the info.

[image: SQL Trace Profiler log]

- The user is actually able to run the SP called *[BizTalkMgmtDb].dbo.[adm_getSettingsForIsolatedHostInstance]* but the SP return no result.
  [image]

On DEV environment, the SP return some value but not in UAT environment.

Yet the data are there :

[image]

Can someone tell me why the SP doesn't return any value ?

Do I missed something during installation of BizTalk Server ?

Comment: Are you App Pools in Started state?  If you View Applications on the App Pool do you see your web service?

Comment: Yes it's started. The issue seems to not be on IIS but in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server name was badly encoded probably due to a bad copy-paste.
When IIS try to run the *adm_getSettingsForIsolatedHostInstance* stored procedure, it tries to compare SRV-BIZ-SQL to SRV(square)BIZ(square)SQL.

Server name has been corrected and everything is fine now.